# How can I save BeautifulSoup object to disk as an XML file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, beautifulsoup

I ran the following code:

```
url_req = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._P._J._Abdul_Kalam"
response = requests.get(url=url_req,verify=True)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
```

How can I save this `soup` object as an XML file to disk?

Comment: That's an HTML and you want to save it as an XML ?

Comment: what do you want to do with the data? why to save it as xml?

Answer (score 2):

You can write the output of `.prettify()` to a file:

```
with open('file.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(soup.prettify())
```